# Transmute hash structure

Tags: ruby, json

I have a large JSON object as such (but x100+):

```
[
    {
        "category": "category1",
        "text": "some text"
    },
    {
        "category": "category2",
        "text": "some more text"
    },
    {
        "category": "category1",
        "text": "even more text"
    }
]
```

How would I transmute this into:

```
{
    "category1": [
        {
            "text": "some text"
        },
        {
            "text": "even more text"
        }
    ],
    "category2": {
        "text": "even more text"
    }
}
```

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean `"category2": { "text": "some more text" }` ? in the second sample?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Or perhaps `"category2": [{"text": "some more text"}]` would be more logically consistent.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Instead of saying "how do I?" you should show your attempt, explain why it doesn't do what you wanted, and then we'll help you debug the problem. As is it's like you haven't done the research and haven't tried as we see no information showing where you've looked and see nothing showing your attempt. Please read "[ask]" and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: Hi Tin Man, except for I could not make an attempt because I hadn't quite figure out how to approach the problem yet. Thanks for your commentary, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to convert your JSON string into Ruby Object.

```
require "json"
json = %{
[
    {
        "category": "category1",
        "text": "some text"
    },
    {
        "category": "category2",
        "text": "some more text"
    },
    {
        "category": "category1",
        "text": "even more text"
    }
]
}
ary = JSON.parse(json)
```

Now that we have an array of hashes in Ruby form, we can manipulate it

```
h = ary.group_by {|i| i["category"]}
#=> {"category1"=>[{"category"=>"category1", "text"=>"some text"}, {"category"=>"category1", "text"=>"even more text"}], "category2"=>[{"category"=>"category2", "text"=>"some more text"}]}

h = h.map {|k,v| {k => v.map {|t| {"text" => t["text"]}}}}
#=> [{"category1"=>[{"text"=>"some text"}, {"text"=>"even more text"}]}, {"category2"=>[{"text"=>"some more text"}]}]

h = h.reduce(&:merge)
#=> {"category1"=>[{"text"=>"some text"}, {"text"=>"even more text"}], "category2"=>[{"text"=>"some more text"}]}
```

Print the JSON in pretty form to check the result

```
puts JSON.pretty_generate(h)
```

Output:

```
{
  "category1": [
    {
      "text": "some text"
    },
    {
      "text": "even more text"
    }
  ],
  "category2": [
    {
      "text": "some more text"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Rather than toss code over the fence, instead explain why the code is appropriate. Don't hand out fish, teach people how to fish so they know what to do the next time and can build upon it.

Comment: Actually, thanks Wand Maker. Seeing it actually working was the best way for me to understand it. Thanks!

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks. Expanded a bit on this one, will try to be more elaborate in future

Answer (score 1):

```
def transmute(arr)
  out = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
  arr.inject(out) do |h, e|
    key = e[:category].to_sym
    entry = {text: e[:text]}        
    h[key] << entry
    h
  end
end
```

Working code/spec snippet:
http://rubysandbox.com/#/snippet/56784c32793916000c000000

Answer (score 1):

Assuming to get `"category2": [{"text": "some more text"}]` in the result:

```
array.map(&:dup).group_by{|h| h.delete(:category)}
```

Comment: I guess you mean ```array.map(&:dup).group_by{|h| h.delete(:category)}```
I'm impressed how concise it is, however it's not 100% what OP wanted: http://rubysandbox.com/#/snippet/56785144793916000c000001

Comment: @cthulhu Right. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Nevermind my remark about you code not doing 100% what was intended - I thought we have ruby hashes, but in fact it was JSON...

Comment: @cthulhu The OP's code can be read as either JSON or Ruby hash. I know it is not the same as what the OP wrote. The question is convoluted. That is why I wrote my assumption.

Comment: I'm working on a code snippet sharing application that encourages asking questions in form of a Spec, would it be possible to contact you in some way to talk about the idea (as you are one of most active users in ruby category)?

Comment: @cthulhu You can leave a comment to me on some random answer of mine, or open a conversation on StackOverflow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98601/discussion-between-cthulhu-and-sawa).

Answer (score 0):

[Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) might help. Something like

```
json.each_with_object({}) do |h, acc|
  acc[h[:category]] ||= []
  acc[h[:category]] << {text: h[:text]}
end # {"category1"=>[{:text=>"some text"}, {:text=>"even more text"}], "category2"=>[{:text=>"some more text"}]}
```

where `json` is your original array.